# php no guarda en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

buenas, estoy haciendo un tutorial de php mvc y tengo el problema de que no me ejecuta el PDO, pense que podria ser problema de xampp, por lo que cambie a wamp, e incluso elimine la instancia de mysql que ya tenia instalada antes, pensando que podria ser un problema de accesos (me comunique con el creador del tutorial, y me dice que el puede realizar la accion sin ningun problema con el codigo que le pase), y como ultima medida probe cambiar de navegador, ya que uso chrome, pero de igual manera, me sigue fallando, y no ingresa al PDO.

Este es mi metodo de usuarios.modelo.php
    static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos){

```
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre, usuario, password, perfil) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":perfil", $datos["perfil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";    

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

este es el fragmento de mi usuarios.controlador.php

```
public function ctrCrearUsuario(){

    if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"])){

            $tabla = "usuarios";

            $datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                           "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                           "password" => $_POST["nuevoPassword"],
                           "perfil" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"]);

            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos);

            if($respuesta == "ok"){

                echo '<script>

                swal({

                    type: "success",
                    title: "¡El usuario ha sido guardado correctamente!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                    closeOnConfirm: false

                })
                </script>';


            }   


        }else{

            echo '<script>

                swal({

                    type: "error",
                    title: "¡El usuario no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                    closeOnConfirm: false

                }).then((result)=>{

                    if(result.value){

                        window.location = "usuarios";

                    }

                })


            </script>';

        }


    }


}
```

esta es mi clase conexion.php

```
class Conexion{
static public function conectar(){
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3308;dbname=pos","root","");
    $link->exec("set names utf8");
    return $link;
}
```

}

para aclarar, descargue el sweetalert2 por lo que esta funcionando correctamente, ya que cuando debe tirar error, lo tira correctamente, y al hacer login en la aplicacion, me loguea correctamente

Comment: en tu funcion conectar debajo de la linea del "new PDO"  agrega $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); y vuelve a probar a ver si te tira algun error.

Comment: lamentablemente, no devuelve ningun tipo de error, simplemente recarga la pagina al querer hacer click en el boton de guardado